# While loop running away

Tags: java, while-loop

My while loop still outputs data even though the condition for the while loop is false.

```
package temperature;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Temperature {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        double tempInput = 0, tempF = 0, counter = 0;



        while (tempInput > -100.-0) {
            System.out.println("Please enter in temperature in Centigrade");
            tempInput = scan.nextDouble();
            tempF = (9.0/5.0)*tempInput + 32.0;
            System.out.print("(F" + tempF + ")");
            System.out.print(" " + "C (" +  tempInput + ")");
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }

}
```

Sample output:

```
Please enter in temperature in Centigrade
-100
(F-148.0) C (-100.0)
```

More:

```
Please enter in temperature in Centigrade
23
(F73.4) C (23.0)
Please enter in temperature in Centigrade
32
(F89.6) C (32.0)
Please enter in temperature in Centigrade
100
(F212.0) C (100.0)
Please enter in temperature in Centigrade
```

Comment: Some of the unused doubles will be used later in the program, but for now I'm trying to get this initial loop to work.

Comment: In the **while** loop condition, get rid of the **.-0** and just have **.0** as in: `while (tempInput > -100.0) {`. You can't enter a double as ** -101.-01**.

Comment: Your loop stops when you enter -100. It displays one final round of conversion and then stops.

Comment: @DevilsHnd `while (tempInput > -100.-0)` is the same as `while (tempInput > -100.0 - 0)`. Doing "minus 0" has no impact.

Comment: @Erwin Bolwidt - As an input for the **Scanner.nextDouble()** method, an entry of say: -100.-0 or -75.-0 or whatever will produce a **InputMismatchException**. I should have clarified that for the nextDouble() method :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you enter the data you are printing it out straight away without checking the condition. Just do another if before the print.

```
package temperature;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Temperature {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        double tempInput = 0, tempF = 0, counter = 0;



        while (tempInput > -100.-0) {
            System.out.println("Please enter in temperature in Centigrade");
            tempInput = scan.nextDouble();
            tempF = (9.0/5.0)*tempInput + 32.0;
            if (tempInput > -100.-0) {
              System.out.print("(F" + tempF + ")");
              System.out.print(" " + "C (" +  tempInput + ")");
              System.out.println("");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The key concept here is that the while condition will be evaluated at the start of each iteration of the loop, not watching the variable for changes as some beginners may think.

Comment: Thank you! I'm new to Java and this was wracking my brain.

Comment: Great @HoboHammer welcome to the party. If you're happy with this answer please accept it as the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

Currently your while loop condition is:

```
while (tempInput > -100.-0) { }
```

`-100.-0` evaluates to -100. The loop stops when `tempInput < -100`, I ran the program and entered in -101 and the loop terminated as it should.

Answer (score 1):

**WHILE LOOP**

The while statement continually executes a block of statements while a particular condition is true. Its syntax can be expressed as:

```
while (expression) {
     statement(s)
}
```

Your Loop will work till the given condition is true :

```
while (tempInput > -100.-0)
```

That is till the time you provide the value of tempInput > -100.0, If you provide a postive value for tempInput like 23 it will check the condition as (23 > -100.0) which is true. Thus the loop will continue executing till the time tempInput is greater than -100.

Answer (score 1):

You could have written:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Temperature {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        double tempInput = 0, tempF = 0, counter = 0;



        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Please enter in temperature in Centigrade");
            tempInput = scan.nextDouble();
            if (tempInput <= -100.0) {
                break;
            }
            tempF = (9.0/5.0)*tempInput + 32.0;
            System.out.print("(F" + tempF + ")");
            System.out.print(" " + "C (" +  tempInput + ")");
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you have written the scanner input in wrong place.

```
package temperature;


import java.util.Scanner;

public class Temperature {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        double tempInput = 0, tempF = 0, counter = 0;
        System.out.println("Please enter in temperature in Centigrade");
        tempInput = scan.nextDouble();

        while (tempInput > -100. - 0) {
            tempF = (9.0 / 5.0) * tempInput + 32.0;
            System.out.print("(F" + tempF + ")");
            System.out.print(" " + "C (" + tempInput + ")");
            System.out.println("");
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What previously happened in your code that ,when while was executing the previous value of tempInput was 0 so while loop will always execute rather in any condition.

Answer (score -2):

As According to me, You will have to defined Scanner as well as double variable outside of the while loop to ensure that at each iteration values can not set to zero for each double variable ex..tempInput = 0, tempF = 0, counter = 0;

this will work.

Answer (score -3):

> Add a else for stopping the loop.

### Example

```
package temperature;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Temperature {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    double tempInput = 0, tempF = 0, counter = 0;



    while (tempInput > -100.-0) {
        System.out.println("Please enter in temperature in Centigrade");
        tempInput = scan.nextDouble();
        tempF = (9.0/5.0)*tempInput + 32.0;
        System.out.print("(F" + tempF + ")");
        System.out.print(" " + "C (" +  tempInput + ")");
        System.out.println("");
    } else {
     //Stopping the loop
   }
}

}
```

Comment: @KartikPrasad Its supposed to compile. If you have error in console, write this here. (Excuse for my english, i speak french) ;)

Comment: Well I am getting a `Temperature.java:17: error: 'else' without 'if`

Comment: Add a if condition ;)

Comment: Thought so, best to post compiling code in your snippets here. I thought you had some feature I hadn't seen.